# Trigger Second Javascript File after Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This should be a simple question, but I can't find an answer on google. I am trying to figure out how to make ajax run another script if the first is successful.

To put it very simply, let's say I have Script1.js which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // Do something
    success: {
        // Run Script2.js
    }
});
```

And Script2.js which looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // Do something
    success: {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Can anyone clue me in on how I would make Script1.js trigger Script2.js to run?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Comment: Wrap the code in script 2 in a function, and call it.

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can use $.getScript to load script file and execute

```
$.ajax({
    // Do something
    success: {
        $.getScript('Script2.js');
        // Run Script2.js
    }
});
```